# Hive UDF gives duplicate result regardless of parameters, when nested in a subquery

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Recently I developed a Hive Generic UDF *getad*. It accepts a map type and a string type parameter and outputs a string value. But I found the UDF output really confusing in different conditions.

Condition A:

```
select
  getad(map_col, 'tp') as tp,
  getad(map_col, 'p') as p,
  getad(map_col, 'sp') as sp
from
  table_name
where
  id = xxxx;
```

The output is right: 'tp', 'p', 'sp'.

Condition B:

```
select
  array(tp, p, sp) as ps
from
  (
  select
    getad(map_col, 'tp') as tp,
    getad(map_col, 'p') as p,
    getad(map_col, 'sp') as sp
  from
    table_name
  where
    id = xxxx
  ) t;
```

The output is wrong: 'tp', 'tp', 'tp'.

Could you please provide me some hints on this?  Thanks!

Comment: A bug, as expressed in the Language Mannual:
Bug for expression caching when UDF nested in UDF or function
Icon
When hive.cache.expr.evaluation is set to true (which is the default) a UDF can give incorrect results if it is nested in another UDF or a Hive function. This bug affects releases 0.12.0, 0.13.0, and 0.13.1. Release 0.14.0 will fix the bug (HIVE-7314).
The problem relates to the UDF's implementation of the getDisplayString method, as discussed in the Hive user mailing list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting hive.cache.expr.evaluation=false, all queries output expected results.

And I found that it's related to the getDisplayString function in the UDF. At first the function returns a string regardless of its parameters. And I had to set hive.cache.expr.evaluation = false.

But after I changed the function to return string in depend of parameters, all queries returned expected results even when the hive.cache.expr.evaluation was set to true.